# Unable to get a css value with jQuery on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I am having some issues trying to develop a functionality on Firefox.

I have this function:

```
var circleColor = function () {
    $('[data-action="user-picture-chart"]').click(function(e) {
        var e = window.event || e;
        $('[data-action="user-picture-sidebar"]').css('borderColor', $(e.target).css('borderColor'));
    });
};
```

Where `$('[data-action="user-picture-sidebar"]')` on Chrome returns:

[image]

And it returns this on Firefox:

[image]

As far as I see it returns the same on both browsers.

If I do `console.log($('[data-action="user-picture-sidebar"]').css('borderColor'));` I get something like this on Chrome: `rgb(190, 190, 190)` but I don't get anything on Firefox so I can't complete my transaction.

Do you know what could be happening?

---

Comment: with firefox, you'd have to do something like `.css('borderTopColor')` - because firefox `getComputedStyle` doesn't return any values for "compound" or "shorthand" attributes

Comment: The comment of @JaromandaX is correct.

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, it worked. Put this as an answer so I can give you the best one.